# Would there be an SEO problem with having a section of "recommended" or "popular" links?

Tags: seo, links, change-frequency

Is there any negative impact of having a "recommended" or "popular" links at the end of an article (in the bottom of the page or in the sidebar)?

I am thinking about that because the popular "block" is changing everyday so all the pages are changing everyday, wouldn't Google be against that?

Comment: Google can very easily separate content from other elements on the page. No worries.